# Open multiple vim tabs and windows simultaneously from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, tabs

I've got four files `a b c d` and would like to open them all in vim such that I have two tabs each vertically splitted into two windows; files `a` and `b` in the first tab and `c` and `d` in the second tab. Can I do this from command line?

I know there are `-p` and `-O` parameters, but they don't seem to cooperate. One only overwrites another from what I observed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command does what you want:

```
$ vim -c "edit a|split b|tabedit c|split d"
```

or, with shortened commands:

```
$ vim -c "e a|sp b|tabe c|sp d"
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to open your files vertically splitted like this:

```
vim -O fileA.txt fileB.txt
vim -O fileC.txt fileD.txt
```

There are also some keys you can use for splitting.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>s</kbd> for horizontal splitting
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>v</kbd> for vertical splitting
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>q</kbd> to close one

But you should know that different Vim instances have independent sessions.
Currently vim does not support to have seperate toplevel’ windows for the same process/session.
It's on the ToDo list. (See `:help todo` and search for "top-level".)

Perhaps the following will brings you further, if you need to share the same buffer between multiple instances of vim: [gnu screen - Working with vim on multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995498/working-with-vim-on-multiple-monitors/4042851?noredirect=1#4042851)